# Force an java application to use specific jre

Tags: java

I have created an java application and it is working in some machine but not in few machines. I am not sure if it is because of the jre.
How can I find the path from which my application uses the jre and how can I force that application to use a jre in a specific location.

Thanks in advance

Comment: JRE comes first, your app comes later. You cannot force app to run inside specific JRE, you can only "gracefully" abort your app if it is run on "wrong" version.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question at hand, Java system properties hold the values you seek:

```
String jreLocation = System.getProperty("java.home");
String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
```

I add the second of these as your problem may be caused by differing versions of Java (if the error is, say, a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError).

In terms of enforcing a particular JRE, it's not possible to force the JVM version from a running Java program (this would need to be in a shell script or similar). You could check the value of "java.home" and exit if it's not the one you want but this would be unwise as this will vary from system to system.  A slightly better options would be to exit with an error message if the "java.version" is not within a set of supported values.

However the best approach would be to fix the original problem such that your program works on all the systems you need it to run on.  To this end, I'd recommend starting a new question with the error you get when running the program on these other systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script file to run a specific JRE, however do note that the problem is most likely not the JRE's fault unless the major version is different.

You cannot force a JRE to be ran in your Java program, because it would be too late.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the path of the JRE being use by checking the value of `java.home` system property. For example:

```
System.out.printf( "java.home = %s\n", System.getProperty( "java.home" ) );
```

Changing the JRE depends, particularly, on how you run your application:

- If you are running your program through a command-line interface, you would need to modify your `PATH` environment variable to point to the correct `java` executable.
- If you are running your program through an IDE, you may need to define a `JRE_HOME` environment variable and restart your IDE, or change the running configuration of your project.

To find out more about other useful properties in Java, take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html.

Answer (score 0):

If your Java application requires a specific JRE, I think your best bet would be to package your application as "self-contained" bundle, containing the JRE. As many have already pointed out, once your application has started, the JRE is already chosen, and the only option you have, is to check the system variables, and possibly quit the application with some error message.

You can read more about the process of creating a self-contained application bundle at Oracle's Deployment Guide: [Self-Contained Application Packaging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).